# How can i remove duplicate key values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

So i'm writing a bit of code and have come to a snag, the snag being i need to remove repeating values from my dictionary. I have seen a few posts on here relating to converting to a tuple and using sets to keep only unique values. However these solutions did not work for me as my value is an integer and not a list.

So just wondering if someone could help/ point the way would be really grateful. Please find the code below.

```
import string
# Variables and the like
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
fname = input('Enter the name of file which contains the cipher text: ')
file = open(fname+'.txt', 'r')
ctext = file.read()
ltrfreq = ['E','T','A','O','I','N','S','R','H','L','D','C','U','M','F','P','G','W','Y','B','V','K','X','J','Q','Z']
freqs = {}

# creating a dictionary which pairs letters to the frequency in the text
for i in alphabet:
    if ctext.count(i) == 0:
        continue
    else:
        freqs[i] = ctext.count(i)
print(freqs)

# Need some code that removes duplicate values so as we don't replace letters that have the same frequency


# Replacing the highest frequency letters with the expected value
n = 0
for i in range(0, len(freqs)):
    maximum = max(freqs, key=freqs.get)
    for j in ctext:
        ctext = ctext.replace(maximum, ltrfreq[n])
    del freqs[maximum]
    n += 1

print(ctext)
```

the file which is the input is just a .txt file which simply contains the following for example purposes:

XULTPAAJCXITLTLXAARPJHTIWTGXKTGHIDHIPXCIWTVGTPILPITGHLXIWIWTXGQADDS

Comment: could you explain a bit more `Replacing the highest frequency letters with the expected value`  what exactly you want to do with the values however you wrote `remove repeating values` in question. kindly clear off with your expected output

Comment: So in the english language there are letters which occur the most frequently which are in the list  'ltrfreq' and the list is ordered. Now the program counts the letters in the sample text and then replaces them with what statistically is  expected. However with frequencies which are the same there is nothing to be said about them and so i would like those not to be replaced.

Comment: Any reason 'O' is missing from that list?

Comment: Simply a typo well spotted thank you :)

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal informative example of input and output, and remove any code which people don't need to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are trying to replace letters in the text by letters based on their frequency. And what you are trying to achieve is that letters with the same frequency are not replaced. That is if `ctext` has same no. of occurrences of A and O (say 4), both of them are not replaced.
To do this, you can change how `freqs` is defined. Currently, it keeps a letter as a key and its frequency as its value.
Instead, try using frequency as key and all letters with that frequency are stored in a list as value.
How that may look like - `{1:["A"], 2:["B", "C"]}`

To achieve that, I believe this code will work -

```
for i in alphabet:
    count = ctext.count(i)
    if count == 0:
        continue
    else:
        freqs[count] = freqs.get(count, []) + [i]
print(freqs)
```

Now you can sort the keys of freqs in descending order and replace letter associated with that frequency only if the size of the list stored as value is 1.
For instance, if one of the keys in `freqs` is 9, just check `if len(freqs[9]) == 1` or not.
If it is, replace the letter given by `freqs[9][0]` by a letter from `ltrfreq` of your choice.

Comment: Fantastic re-modified my code and working like a charm now